# (Minecraft Java 1.14) CanPlaceOn tag not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map, and I want players to get a button that can be placed on a gold block. The command worked in version 1.13, but now it just doesn’t.

The command I used was:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_button{CanPlaceOn:[“Minecraft:gold_block”]}
```

Comment: Try `minecraft` without a capital "M". Also, what are those quote characters? You have to use the normal ones: `"`

Comment: Those were just typos, sorry. Also I don’t think it is the spelling because that whole thing turns green.

Comment: i don't think this is an issue with OP's command or anything, actually. i tried it myself on 1.14, and despite clearly having the NBT tag (seeing as having Advanced Tooltips of told me so) it allowed me to place it anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You should write specific number of block/item such as
/give @p minecraft:stone_button 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:gold_block"]}

Comment: That is the syntax for versions prior to 1.13, and is therefore irrelevant in a 1.4 question